# amazon <p> web scraping with python 3, requests and bs4

Tags: python-3.x

current i run code if use headers then ->print list = empty but if i not use headers then ->print list = have data but a bit will bug `503 Server Error: Service Unavailable` if use for. i don't understand why use header then list = empty.
thanks help me

```
import bs4
import requests

headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 7.0; Win64; x64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0"}
res = requests.get('https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07GMXQN8X', headers=headers)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.content,'html.parser')
a = soup.find_all('p')
print(a)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to work with `res.text` and not `res.content`. Also, you might try changing the [parser](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser):

```
import bs4
import requests

headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 7.0; Win64; x64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0"}
res = requests.get('https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07GMXQN8X', headers=headers)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html5lib')
# soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')

a = soup.find_all('p')
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[<p>Sponsored Products are advertisements for products sold by merchants on Amazon.com. When you click on a Sponsored Product ad, you will be taken to an Amazon detail page where you can learn more about the product and purchase it.</p>, <p>        To learn more about Amazon Sponsored Products,<span class="a-letter-space"></span>        <a class="a-link-normal" href="https://advertising.amazon.com/products-self-serve?ref_=ext_amzn_wtsp" rel="noopener" target="_blank" title="click here">click here</a>.    </p>, <p class="a-spacing-small a-size-small a-color-secondary">
    Find answers in product info, Q&amp;As, reviews
  </p>, <p class="a-spacing-base a-spacing-top-base a-color-error askError askBadQuestionError">
            Please make sure that you are posting in the form of a question.
          </p>, <p>Sponsored Products are advertisements for products sold by merchants on Amazon.com. When you click on a Sponsored Product ad, you will be taken to an Amazon detail page where you can learn more about the product and purchase it.</p>, <p>        To learn more about Amazon Sponsored Products,<span class="a-letter-space"></span>        <a class="a-link-normal" href="https://advertising.amazon.com/products-self-serve?ref_=ext_amzn_wtsp" rel="noopener" target="_blank" title="click here">click here</a>.    </p>, <p class="nav_p nav-bold">There's a problem loading this menu right now.</p>, <p class="nav_p"><a class="nav_a" href="/gp/prime/ref=nav_prime_ajax_err/145-9045450-0196650">Learn more about Amazon Prime.</a></p>]
```

Comment: Did you try to execute this?

Comment: problem is you run code if not headers then sure code run ok but a bit will error 503 Server Error: Service Unavailable

Comment: my bad... I didn't understand this from your question. @DeepSpace, I see your point.

Comment: Okey, it's no problem :) @WilliamLabaguette , so do u have any idea to solve this ?

Comment: @BaoQuyetNguyen did my last edit was of any help ? If so, could you please validate my answer or add an answer you found out working ? Thanks.

Comment: @WilliamLabaguette hello .  after i run code 20 minutes then error, i don't understand that user-agent ? is good will no happen error